# Show block indent levels/ lines in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, indentation

Working in Visual Studio Code I can see indent levels like so

[image]

Which is pretty useful for long chunks of code and functions.

---

Working in Jupyter Notebooks I couldnt find an option to show similar.

[image]

Anybody aware of a setting or nbextension for such?

Thank you